# find the exact length of the curve y=ln(sec(x)) between x=0 and x=pi/4

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

Find the exact length of the curve y=ln(sec(x)) between 0 and pi/4.

First do I find dy/dr?

Comment: I'm not sure I see what you mean. The length of $y=f(x)$ from $x=a$ to $x=b$ is $\int_a^b \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2} dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arc length is $\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1+(y')^2}\text{d}x$ so $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\ln \sec x=\frac{\sec x \tan x}{\sec x}=\tan x$ so the arc length from 0 to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ is $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sqrt{1+\tan^2 x}\text{d}x=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sec x\text{d}x=$ $$\ln\left | \sec x +\tan x \right |\rvert_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}=\ln (\sqrt 2+1)$$

Comment: is a u-substitution used?

Comment: Nope, just gotta know what the integral of sec x is.

Comment: if I set u=secx du=secxtanx, plugging this in I have integral ln(u)du= (1/u)*du= secxtanx/secx.

Comment: Yeah that's how you take the derivative

Comment: wouldnt sec(pi/4)+tan(pi/4) = sqrt(2) +1.... and sec(0)+tan(0)=1+0 so answer would be ln(√2+1)-ln(1)?

Comment: Yes but the ln 1 is 0 so we can leave it out